# How to put array "[ ]" brackets in swagger with laravel comment?

Tags: php, swagger, laravel-5.5

I am not able to write JSON code in an example with array brackets.

```
@SWG\Definition(
 *      definition="UserResponse",
 *      @SWG\Property(property="response", example={
 *               "id": 1,
 *               "name": "Raj",
 *               "userprofile": [{
 *                    "email": "raj@gmail.com",
 *                    "phone": "9999999999",
 *               }],  
 *               "updated_at": "2017-03-06 12:03:12",
 *               "created_at": "2017-03-06 12:03:12"
 *             }
 *      ),
 * ),
 */
```

I want this kinds of out using swagger response **Output**:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Raj",
   "userprofile": [
       {
         "email": "raj@gmail.com",
         "phone": "9999999999",
       }
   ],  
   "updated_at": "2017-03-06 12:03:12",
   "created_at": "2017-03-06 12:03:12"
}
```

According to above code, I want these kinds of output:
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add "{" curly braces "}" , hence it will consider array "[]" brackets.

```
@SWG\Definition(
 *      definition="UserResponse",
 *      @SWG\Property(property="response", example={
 *               "id": 1,
 *               "name": "Raj",
 *               "userprofile": {{
 *                    "email": "raj@gmail.com",
 *                    "phone": "9999999999",
 *               }},  
 *               "updated_at": "2017-03-06 12:03:12",
 *               "created_at": "2017-03-06 12:03:12"
 *             }
 *      ),
 * ),
 */
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, let me check and let you know same.